# Predict the injury time of a football match?

Tags: r, machine-learning, generalized-linear-model, predictive-models

I have a project which requires me to predict the injury time of a football match. And I have the relevant information, such as goals, corners, referee, 2 team names and the injury time for each half.

I tried to use Poisson regression and I am a little confused about the model building.

I added the factor "referee" into the glm model and the summary told me that only some of the referees have a significant effect on the results. So I wonder how I can check whether I should include referee as a factor in the model? If I should, is it correct to add the referee into the model directly?

Thanks!

Comment: When you say that you add "referee" to the model, do you mean that you include several categories of referees (e.g. "Brad was the ref", "Ronald was the ref"...)?

Comment: @Dave. Yes. "referee" is a categorical variable with hundreds of levels (one referee for one level".

Comment: I wonder if you should treat referee as a random effect.